# Spring create bean only if condition is met

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Assume there are two implementations of a single interface, and these beans are declared as beans in the spring configuration xml. Now, I would need only one implementation of the interface based on the system property. And, I don't wanna create the second implementation of the bean. How can I do this? I looked at this blog but then below snippet of the code from this blog uses "new" operate to create the beans. In my case the beans are declared in the spring configuration file.

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/

```
@CONFIGURATION
PUBLIC CLASS MYCONFIGURATION {

  @BEAN(NAME="EMAILERSERVICE")
  @CONDITIONAL(WINDOWSCONDITION.CLASS)
  PUBLIC EMAILSERVICE WINDOWSEMAILERSERVICE(){
      RETURN NEW WINDOWSEMAILSERVICE();
  }

  @BEAN(NAME="EMAILERSERVICE")
  @CONDITIONAL(LINUXCONDITION.CLASS)
  PUBLIC EMAILSERVICE LINUXEMAILERSERVICE(){
    RETURN NEW LINUXEMAILSERVICE();
  }
```

Comment: What determines whether one or the other is to be used? Also post the relevant configuration.

Comment: Well, the current configuration is just the implementation beans declared in spring context files, thats about it. And, what determines one or the other is a system property.